# Group by unique column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a simple table `posts` like

```
user_id
created
```

Now, I want to summarize the number of posts per month, I use the query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`created`,'%Y-%m') AS d,
       count(*) AS total
FROM posts
GROUP BY d
ORDER BY d;
```

Which is okay, however, if I want to know **the number of unique users' posts** per month (i.e. user_id), how to do it?

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT something)

Comment: By " the number of unique users' posts per month" you mean you want to know for each month the number of different users that made at least one post ?

Answer (score 0):

You must group by `user_id` also:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(`created`,'%Y-%m') AS d,
  user_id AS u,
  count(*) AS total
FROM posts
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`created`,'%Y-%m'), user_id
ORDER BY d;
```

This will give you posts for each user for a given date. I suppose the other answer is more correct for that you need.

Also I am not sure that you can `GROUP BY` alias `d`. In SQL Server this is an error. I am not so familiar with MySql.

Answer (score 0):

If by "the number of unique users' posts per month" you mean you want to know for each month the number of different users (different user_id) that made at least one post :

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(`created`,'%Y-%m') AS d,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS total
FROM posts
GROUP BY d
ORDER BY d;
```

If you meant for each month, the list of different users that made at least one post, and count this number then :

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    DATE_FORMAT(`created`,'%Y-%m') AS d,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM posts
GROUP BY d, user_id
ORDER BY d, user_id;
```